# rangeOfString and encoding

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to parse the output of a shell command I executed using NSTask. Looking for a specific substring would be sufficient, only the substring is never found.

My code so far:

```
NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                               encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(string);

if([string rangeOfString:@"Connection refused"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

It always prints "not found" even though the substring searched for is contained in the variable *string*. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Am amazed but when i wrote the condition in reverse. It worked. 
Please check below example:

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla Connection refused Connection refused bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"Connection refused"].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain Connection refused");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string contains Connection refused!");
}
```

Hope i am clear..

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as easy as that. When I initialize the string that I'm searching in as you did, rangeOfString works as expected (even with the non-reversed condition). The problem seems to be with the conversion of the output of the executed command to the NSString (maybe encoding or something?).

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken. The output of the command is in fact empty (so the string looked for wasn't found obviously). What I expected the result of the NSLog call was in fact the output of the command directly to the console (stderr? ). Sorry for that :(.